# What to use in place of AppRegistry in Create React Native app without ejecting

Tags: reactjs, react-native, create-react-app, create-react-native-app

I am reading a tutorial written without create-react-native app and it has used exponent .. The code that I see in the tutorial is:

```
let React = require('react-native')
let { AppRegistry, Component,Text} = React;

class .....{

render(){return();}
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('main',()=> className);
```

Because AppRegistry seems to not work as I am using create-react-native app and I don't want to eject, what can I use instead of AppRegistry?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In my App.js I just export a root component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import AppWithNavigationState from './app/components/AppWithNavigationState';
import settings from './app/config/settings';

import reducers from './app/reducers';


export default class Root extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const {
        dev,
        DEVELOPMENT,
        PRODUCTION,
    } = settings;

    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey              : dev ? DEVELOPMENT.FIREBASE_APIKEY         : PRODUCTION.FIREBASE_APIKEY,
        authDomain          : dev ? DEVELOPMENT.FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN     : PRODUCTION.FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
        databaseURL         : dev ? DEVELOPMENT.FIREBASE_URL            : PRODUCTION.FIREBASE_URL,
        projectId           : dev ? DEVELOPMENT.FIREBASE_PRODUCT_ID     : PRODUCTION.FIREBASE_PRODUCT_ID,
        storageBucket       : dev ? DEVELOPMENT.FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET  : PRODUCTION.FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
        messagingSenderId   : dev ? DEVELOPMENT.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_ID   : PRODUCTION.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_ID,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <AppWithNavigationState />
            </View>
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```